# How to initialize MultiValuedMap - apache commons library in Java

Tags: java

I have key-value structure with duplicate key values. Thus, I use MultiValuedMap. Key and value types are double. However, I am not sure how to initialize this structure.

```
static MultiValuedMap<Double, Double> candidateRange;    
// following line will generate an error
candidateRange = new MultiValuedMap<Double, Double>();
```

Answer (score 4):

Although the docs talk about a `MultiValuedHashMap`, I can't find it. Instead, I use a [`HashSetValuedHashMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/multimap/HashSetValuedHashMap.html):

```
MultiValuedMap<Double, Double> candidateRange = new HashSetValuedHashMap<>();
```

Comment: Even though the question is relatively poor, this was probably his problem as well. There is no such class as a MultiValuedHashMap and their documentation seems to be out of date.

Answer (score 4):

I can't find `MultivaluedHashMap` either. You may want to use `ArrayListValuedHashMap` instead as it follows.

```
MultiValuedMap<K, V> map = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<K, V>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Not enough to go by, you should read the documentation.

Here are the docs, with a map initialised and values added: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html

`MultiValuedMap<K, String> map = new MultiValuedHashMap<K, String>();`

Comment: You could also include the example directly ` MultiValuedMap<K, String> map = new MultiValuedHashMap<K, String>();`

Answer (score 2):

It is like initializing `Map` interface with `HashMap`,

```
    MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = new MultivaluedHashMap<>();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.add("x-authorization", "1bdc5db0-dfc8-43f2-9159-3827bfe48ea7.1587315996051");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also initialize a MultiValuedMap without the need of an external library. Example:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> headers = CollectionUtils.toMultiValueMap(Map.of("Content-Type", List.of("application/json")));
```